# English word list with pronunciation

Tags: pronunciation, dictionaries

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I obtain an English dictionary with structured data?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3442/where-can-i-obtain-an-english-dictionary-with-structured-data)

Where can I find a digital English-language dictionary or word list containing pronunciation? I would prefer something under an open source or similar license.

Answer (score 1):

[Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary%3aMain_Page) is free, contains [IPA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet) pronunciations, and is licensed under [Creative Commons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creative_Commons).

If you aren't looking for IPA, [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/) is free and contains pronunciation, but is not open source.