# Dictionary of English word syllables and stresses

Tags: dictionaries

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I obtain an English dictionary with structured data?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3442/where-can-i-obtain-an-english-dictionary-with-structured-data)

Does anybody know of a downloadable dictionary of English words with their syllables AND stress patterns? I want to do some analysis of rhythms in texts but haven't been able to find such a database. For instance, I'd want to be able to feed my script a line and have it tell me if it is iambic or not.

Comment: The links in the duplicate question give online resources that you can use for syllabification, stress, POS etc. Of course you still have to deal with ambiguously stressed words that could pose a problem, and poetic license (where the natural stress doesn't fit the meter but somehow it 'works').

Comment: If you post this on a software development forum, instead of an English language forum, who knows?  You might inspire someone to create an app for that.

Comment: Strange that this was marked as a duplicate. The linked question doesn't ask about syllable or stress pattern specifically. It does mention pronunciation, but often pronunciation data doesn't include full information about syllables. And it was not clear from the answers which, if any, of the online resources mentioned included information on stress and syllable structure. I just added an answer there but maybe it belonged more to this question.

Answer (score 1):

[Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary%3aAbout) might be a good bet.

However, if you're looking to scan texts, [The Google Books API](http://code.google.com/apis/books/docs/v1/getting_started.html) might be interesting.

Comment: Wiktionary doesn't consistently have pronunciation data; where it does, it doesn't consistently include syllable divisions.